# Solr - execute different query based on condition

Tags: solr

I have 50 value fields, 50 booleans and a date field. To be compliant to the new GDPR standard, I need to make certain fields unsearchable. The difficult part in my case is, the fields that need to be unsearchable differ per record. So in one case field 2 and 5 might be protected, while in the other field 3 and 7 are protected. This is known by the booleans: every value field also has a boolean that defines if that field is protected or not.

All this only applies when the date field is still in the future. When the date is in the past, or there is no date at all, all fields of that record are searchable anyway, regardless of the booleans.

What I had in mind is execute a different query per record, based on whether or not the date field of that record is in the future.
if (date > today) -> query1
else -> query2

Where query1 checks every field individually, taking into account the matching boolean. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: If you want to make it unsearchable from solr side, then I don't think that it's possible, because searchable is defined by property called `indexed` in `schema.xml`. Instead, you can write your logic in the programming language from which you are hitting API call to solr cores.

Answer (score 0):

For the first condition - use separate fields for searching before and after the date has passed (if you can still store the value - i'm not not too familiar with detailed GDPR requirements).

I.e. have `field_1`, `field_1_before_date` - and only submit a value for `field_1_before_date` if your boolean value is true when indexing the document.

Issue two separate queries, one to get documents in the future and one to get documents in the past - in the first one you limit the fields you query to `field_1_before_date`, while in the second one you use `field_1` instead.

You can combine these using `_query_` - [Using nested queries in Solr](https://lucidworks.com/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/):

```
q=yourfirstquery OR _query_:"your second query"
```

.. should work, unless there is a limitation to combining those using OR.

Comment: The date I meant isn't a fixed date. To give an example: certain records become searchable once the person dies. So the date is filled in once this happen.

Comment: Updated comment:
The date I meant isn't a fixed date. It can for example be 50 years in the future, depending on the type of document. Some documents get public once the linked person is deceased, so then the date changes to an earlier date and suddenly all fields get searchable.

I also need to be able to tell how many hidden records there are. A hidden record is one where the search criteria matches, but it only matched in a protected field. In this case the result may not be returned, but I need to know there was a result.

Comment: But if it's not 50 years in the future on a certain date, there really isn't a date set (i.e. if it keeps moving ahead, it'll never be true). Storing the date when the content becomes available doesn't work? (i.e. if the document was stored today, you'd set the date to `2068-05-08`) .. for the second case you can implement it by having a third field; field_1_hidden_data and then search against that field.